# How to Add/delete rows in grid view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I need to add/delete rows like gird as show in the below screenshot. My intention is to add "Name" and "Mark" to the grid one by one. By default the grid should show only three items. Once the grid exceeds three rows it should be in scroll. I used "Scroll view" for this but I face below problems while implementing this.

1) How to add the items to the grid onnce I enter "Name" and "Mark" and press the "Add" button?

2) How to control the grid height to show only "three" items by default?

3) How to make scroll after "three items" added to the grid.

Can some one provide me code snippets or any sample projects to startup as below screen-shot.

[image: Iphone App]

Comment: You need to create custom UIView and it on UIScrollView also name , mark and delete is UILabel 'x' sign is your custom button and..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/slysid/iOS

Hope this is what you are looking for. It is not 100% done but it will do the job. I have used UITableview and a subclass of UITableview cell to make the view scrollable. You can find the source code in above link.

Bharath

Comment: Thanks Bharath. One more help I want to add one more column in table cell. Can you please advice to me where i will add the one more column

Answer (score 1):

You can find sample project at https://github.com/slysid/iOS

Bharath